# Собрать jar из JavaFX проекта

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Написал небольшое приложение выбрав шаблон `JavaFX` в `Idea`. Из Idea запускается, работает. Собрал в `jar` файл следующим образом как на рисунке, но когда запускаю `jar` ничего не происходит. Что я не так сделал?

Использовалась `JDK 12`. Знаю что `JavaFX` вырезали из него, но я добавил библиотеки `JavaFX` и при создании артефакта вроде все библиотеки добавил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На странице https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ написано ввести set PATH_TO_FX_MODS="path\to\javafx-jmods-13"
jlink --module-path "%PATH_TO_FX_MODS%;mods\production" --add-modules hellofx --output jre
jre\bin\java -m hellofx/org.openjfx.MainApp, чтобы создать кастомный образ для выполнения. Что это имеется ввиду и где нужно ввести данные команды? В командной строке?

Comment: запустите jar из консоли, там будет подробное описание ошибки с которой можно работать.

Comment: Запускал были ошибки связанные с JavaFX классами.. В итоге написал приложение на Java 8. Попробую завтра в вопрос добавить ошибки из jar файла на Java 12. Как я понял нужно через модули как-то связку сделать Java 12 и JavaFX